# Calculate last three years total vehicle count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My lookup table data is look like this as below: The database is SQL Server.

| policy_number | policy_eff_dt | lob_cd | Number_of_vehicles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-10-12 | AUTO | 5 |
| 1234 | 2021-10-12 | AUTO | 6 |
| 1234 | 2020-10-12 | AUTO | 3 |
| 1234 | 2019-10-12 | AUTO | 2 |

My source table provide the following filter columns are Policy_number, policy_eff_dt, LOB_CD

If the incoming (source) values are policy_number=1234, policy_eff_dt=2022-10-12, loc_cd=AUTO

then I should identify the previous three years (2021,2020, 2019) and sum up the (6+3+2) = 11 as PREV3_TOTAL_NBR_OF_VEHICLES.

My filter conditions are

```
in_policy_number = policy_number and

in_policy_eff_dt <= policy_eff_dt and

in_lob_cd = lob_cd
```

In this way, I will get the 2021, 2020 and 2019)

I thought about subquery to get the previous 3 year of rows. I need some kind of help here.

Is there a way to compose a query to calculate this total number of vehicles?

Note: this is the initial query developed:

```
select 
   policy_num, lob_cd, sum(number_of_vehicles) 
from table1 
where policy_num='S 2455350'  
    and lob_cd = 'AU'  
    and year(policy_eff_dt) >= '2022'-3  
    and year(policy_eff_dt) <= '2022' 
group by policy_num , lob_cd
```

NEW SQL:

```
select A.policy_num, A.lob_cd, A.policy_eff_dt,sum(NUM1+NUM2+NUM3) as PREV3_NUMBER_OF_VEHICLES from (select  policy_num, lob_cd,curr. A.policy_eff_dt,  case when year (curr.policy_eff_dt) - year (prev.policy_eff_dt) =1 then prev.number_of_vehicles else 0 end) as NUM1, case when year (curr.policy_eff_dt) - year (prev.policy_eff_dt) =2 then prev.number_of_vehicles else 0 end as NUM2, case when year(curr.policy_eff_dt) - year (prev.policy_eff_dt) =3 then prev.number_of_vehicles else 0 end as NUM3 from table1 curr 
     left join table1 prev  on curr.policy_num=prev.policy_num  and curr.lob_cd = prev.lob_cd where curr.policy_num='S 2455350'  
    and curr.lob_cd = 'AU'  ) A
```

group by  A.policy_num, A.lob_cd, A.policy_eff_dt

Comment: Format your code properly.  No one is going to read your post.

Comment: Also, have you tried anything???

Comment: This is initial query developed and trying to automate:                                         
  select policy_num, lob_cd, sum(number_of_vehicles)
      FROM table1
        where policy_num='S  2455350'                                                                        
           and lob_cd = 'AU' 
           and year(policy_eff_dt) >= '2022'-3 
           and year(policy_eff_dt) <= '2022'                                                                
         group by policy_num, lob_cd

Comment: I am trying to automate this in a way when the incoming policy year is 2022, then i should go back to 2021, 2020, 2019 and add the number of vehicles column

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77326565/edit) your question with updates rather then use the comments, it's hard to read. Also use the formatting tools provided to make your question easier to read . Have read of this to help your questions better and more likely to get answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Having read the question again, your query seems to do what you wanted (although you should use YEAR() on the passed in date rather then relying on the implicit casting of the '2022' string to a number. So what is the issue? If this is not what you want the final output to be, then show your expected results

Comment: My scenario is source table is table1, i read the first record and policy effective year 2022, then i have to read previous three year (such as 2021, 2020, 2019) and sum up the column 'NUMBER_OF_VEHICLES'

Comment: I have added my new sql. Please share your comments.

Comment: I have updated my final sql along with questions. we can close this question

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem by simplifying it up front using declared variables.
Generally I would figure out the max policy date for the policy number, then do a dateadd -3 years for the 3 years ago start date.  The advantage here is the final query is sargable by avoiding the Year() function.

```
--Specify the policy_number
DECLARE @policynum int = 1234;

--Get the most recent policy_eff_dt for the policynum
DECLARE @MaxPolicyDate date = (SELECT MAX(policy_eff_dt) WHERE policy_number = @policynum);

--Get start date 3 years prior
DECLARE @startdate date = DATEADD(YEAR, -3, @MaxPolicyDate);


--Main Query
SELECT policy_num
      ,lob_cd
      ,SUM(Number_of_vehicles) AS [PREV3_TOTAL_NBR_OF_VEHICLES]
  FROM table1
 WHERE policy_num = @policynum
   AND policy_eff_dt >= @startdate
   AND Policy_eff_dt < @MaxPolicyDate

GROUP BY policy_num,lob_cd
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `APPLY` operator to get the SUM of the previous 3 years. I've given below a working example to give an idea.
The column strict_prev3_total_nbr_of_vehicles will give the SUM only when there are exactly 3 previous years available and the column prev3_total_nbr_of_vehicles will give the SUM of the 3 previous years whether available or not .

```
drop table if exists table1
go
create table table1 (
    policy_number int,
    policy_eff_dt date,
    lob_cd char(4),
    Number_of_vehicles int)
go
INSERT into table1
values (1234, '2022-10-12', 'AUTO', 5),
(1234, '2021-10-12', 'AUTO', 6),
(1234, '2020-10-12', 'AUTO', 3),
(1234, '2019-10-12', 'AUTO', 2)
GO
select a.*,
       prev3_total_nbr_of_vehicles,
       case
            when p.total_prev_years = 3 then p.prev3_total_nbr_of_vehicles
            else 0 end strict_prev3_total_nbr_of_vehicles
  from table1 a
 outer apply (   select sum(Number_of_vehicles) prev3_total_nbr_of_vehicles,
                        count(1) total_prev_years
                   from table1 b
                  where a.policy_number = b.policy_number
                    and a.lob_cd        = b.lob_cd
                    and YEAR(b.policy_eff_dt) BETWEEN YEAR(a.policy_eff_dt) - 3 and YEAR(a.policy_eff_dt) - 1) p
GO
```